# How can I find text in a file and replace it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I need to write a function for the gulp.
The function should:
**1.** Open file (**style.min.css**)
**2.** Find all lines with the given text (**img/sprite.png**)
**3.** Replace all found lines with (**../img/sprite.png**)

To simplify the task, I include a plugin (**replace-in-file**)
I am not good at Node.js but I tried...
Please help me make it right.
If you want you can show how to do this without using a plugin (**replace-in-file**).
But you can also use the plugin...

```
const build = ('build/')
const replace = require('replace-in-file')
const config = {
    build: {
        style: build + 'css'
    }
}

function fixSprites() {
    const results = replace.sync({
        files: config.build.style + '/style.min.css',
        from: 'img/sprite.png',
        to: '../img/sprite.png',
        countMatches: true,
    })
    return src(config.build.style + '/style.min.css')
        .pipe(replace(results))
}

exports.fixSprites = fixSprites()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a plugin 'replace-in-file'!
This is the out of the box gulp solution
Replace all lines of a similar type with others.
Example: replace img/sprite.png with ../img/sprite.png

[image]

```
const { series } = require('gulp')
const replace = require('replace-in-file')

function updateRedirects(done) {
    replace({
        files: 'build/css/style.min.css',
        from: /img\/sprite.png/g, // img/sprite.png – Replace this.
        to: '../img/sprite.png', // ../img/sprite.png – Replace with this.
        countMatches: true,
    }, done)
}

exports.build = series(updateRedirects) // Start
```